# Recusive Lazy Loading Problem

Tags: .net, subsonic3, lazy-loading

How to avoid recursive mapping in Lazy loading technique at self join Entity?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using .Net as development Framework & for Dal >> Subsonic 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify the T4 templates. `Classes.tt` is responsible for generating the object models.  The implementation of relationship properties (that is where the lazy loading happens) is in that file.

It's an ugly solution, but the only work around I am aware of.

We ended up defining an array of table+field names that should be generated as one-way relationships, and modified the `Classes.tt` file to not generate relationships in both directions.  In fact, we've made many modifications to the templates to work around issues inherent to SubSonic.